# Tweening a object-based d3.svg.arc diagram (without redrawing it).

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My Tween function (below) does not work correctly. The console shows the correct steps of the endAngle attribute of the arc. But the HTML inspector shows some NaN and null values instead of the correct arc-values.

```
function tweenEndAngle() {
  return function () {
    var startAngle = d3.select(this).attr("start");
    var endAngle = d3.select(this).attr("end");
    var inner = d3.select(this).attr("inner");
    var outer = d3.select(this).attr("outer");
    //alert("start:" +startAngle+", end:"+endAngle);
    var i = d3.interpolateNumber(endAngle, startAngle);
    return function (t) {
        console.log(i(t));
        //the concole shows the correct steps but the arc is not drawn correctly
        d3.select(this).attr("d", d3.svg.arc()
                             .startAngle(function(){return startAngle;})
                             .endAngle(function(){return i(t);})
                             .innerRadius(function(){return inner;})
                             .outerRadius(function(){return outer;})
                            );
    }
  }
}
```

The correct behaviour should be: on mouse-over each arc should shrink to its startangle.

Here is the fiddle: [JS Fiddle link to my arc Diagram](http://jsfiddle.net/olafponeta/u6E2Q/2/)

Please fix or point me to the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: It may be easier to start from a working example like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems I found:

1. On the lines where you set the inner and outer attributes, you cannot have return on a separate line from the return value - this is why you were getting null for the inner and outer attributes.
2. You need to convert the values to numbers in your tweening function:

   ```
   var startAngle = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("start"));
   var endAngle = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("end"));
   var inner = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("inner"));
   var outer = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("outer"));
   ```

Working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/L2Vwh/